# recursive function or non-recursive that doesnt use 2 ** approach

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi there im working on a question and am not sure if I have done it correctly as I didn't quite follow the hint as I think its wrong and uses `+` instead of `x`. This is the question:

Write a program that contains a recursive function that returns 2n, for any integer `n`, `n ≥ 0`. (HINT: `2n = 2 * 2n-1` when `n > 0`.) (You can also try to do this non-recursively). Ask the user for the number n and return the appropriate value. Do not use the `2 ** n` approach.

This is what I have written:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Please enter a value for x: "))
    print("The answer is: ", times2(x))
def times2(n):
   result = 0
   while n:
       result += 2
       n -= 1
   return result
main()
```

It basically multiplied every input by two, im not sure if this is right and not really sure if I read the question right... please help!

Comment: You should ask specific questions on this assignment, not post the assignment itself.

Comment: Do you mean `2**n` (2 to the power of n)? `2n == 2*n`

Comment: Are you looking for multiplicity (2 times 2) or exponentiation (2 squared)?

Comment: @Makoto: I don't know why you decided to pick `x == 2`...

Comment: The very least you could do is google what the `**` operator does.

Comment: Did you copy and paste `2n` from rich text? Is the N superscript? `2n = 2 * 2n-1` simplifies to `2n = 4n - 1`, which is wrong for `n != 0.5`...

Comment: @Eric not if (n-1) is in parentheses (which I think it might be), though even then, the hint doesn't really make any sense. And why you would need a recursive function for multiplication doesn't either.

Comment: @Eric though looking at this again, 2^n = 2 * 2^(n-1) would make sense as well if (n-1) is in superscript, and then this hint would start to make a **lot** more sense. However, that would work for any real number n, not just n > 0, so maybe not...

Answer (score 3):

Taking your question literally:

```
def double(n, stop_recursion=False):
    if stop_recursion:
        return n
    else:
        return double(2 * n, stop_recursion=True)
```

Does it call itself? Yes, so it's recursive

Does it use `2 ** n`? No

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to do `2**n`...

Thus, you can do:

```
def power2(n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    return 2 * power2(n - 1)
```

It is recursive because it calls itself, does not literally use `2**n`, and works for whatever number you want that is greater than 0.

Comment: Why not have it return 1 if n is 0 instead of 2 if n is 1 so that it will work even if n is zero?

Answer (score 1):

For a power function that will work for any number A taken to the power of any whole number B:

```
def a_power_b(a, b):
    if b > 0:
        return a_power_b(a, b - 1) * a
    elif b < 0:
        return a_power_b(a, b + 1) / a
    else:
        return 1
```

Furthermore, if you are indeed doing multiplication recursively you could use:

```
def a_times_b(a, b):
    if b > 0:
        return a_times_b(a, b - 1) + a
    elif b < 0:
        return a_times_b(a, b + 1) - a
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: It's probably worth preventing `a_power_b(x, 0.5)` recursing infinitely

Comment: I was thinking about how to add support for -1 < b < 1, but I can't think of a clean way to do it without using the built in power function. I'm not on a computer right now, but I'd bet Wikipedia could offer a nice formula to use

Comment: I was thinking more `if -1 < b < 1 and b != 0: raise ValueError`